# Transfer from one workbook to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

VBA Code to transfer from one workbook to another. For example I have a workbook with multiple sheets for each department. Once the items are completed I manually copy and paste to the completed workbook. I need help creating a VBA Code that will update only the completed items to the completed master workbook. I tried the following VBA code but it transfers all the worksheets to one worksheet and that is not what I am looking for.

```
Sub SummurizeSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Sales").Activate
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Sales" Then
            ws.Range("A2:K45").Copy
            Worksheets("Sales").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

I need *Cell A2:I45* to copy the items that have been completed to a master workbook if cell I has **completed** on it. Hope this makes sense, otherwise I can attach the excel workbooks.
So, I have 4 worksheets for each sales location. for example worksheet1 is Sales, then the other Sales2...ect...All worksheets contain the same data but different department areas edit each worksheet, this is why there are multiple worksheets. Once they are all completed by each department, I want those 4 worksheets to transfer to one worksheet in the completed workbook.

Comment: Clarification, so you copy and paste each department worksheet to another workbook with the same per department worksheet but only contains those that are completed? And not consolidate all the worksheet to one?

Comment: Well, what I have an excel spreadsheet with multiple departments and each sheet contains the same header row. Each department adds there comments and changes to their corresponding department and marks the each item complete or pending. All the completed items from each department tab get transferred over to a completed excel workbook. We only use the worksheet with multiple tabs for data entry and updates until they are completed. So we do consolidate all the completed items in one at the end of the month and delete them from the each tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated:

```
Sub SummarizeSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rw As Range, cDest As Range
    Dim wbDest As Workbook, wbSource As Workbook
    Dim rngSrc As Range, x As Long

    Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook 'set source of data

    ' set the destination for completed items: adjust names to suit
    Set wbDest = Workbooks("Completed.xlsx") ' must be already open !
    Set cDest = wbDest.Worksheets("Complete").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each ws In wbSource.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Sales" Then
            Set rngSrc = ws.Range("A2:K45")
            ' step backwards since we might be deleting rows...
            For x = rngSrc.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
                Set rw = rngSrc.Rows(x)
                If UCase(rw.Cells(1, "I").Value) = "COMPLETED" Then
                    cDest.Resize(1, rw.Columns.Count).Value = rw.Value
                    rw.EntireRow.Delete            'delete from source
                    Set cDest = cDest.Offset(1, 0) 'set next destination row
                End If
            Next x
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the code but it did not work. So what I have is a summary sheet with cells from A through I and "I" is the row with that will indicate if the item is completed or pending and all completed items need to be transferred over to the completed workbook and deleted once complete. I do have multiple sheets but I can run macro one at a time.

Comment: Does the "completed" workbook have the same worksheet names as the source workbook, or is there just a single sheet?  What value in Col I indicates an item is complete in the source worksheet? (you mention Col K above - is it now I ?)

Comment: Yes the completed workbook does not have the same names as the source workbook. It is just one worksheet storing all the data from the source workbook. And yes my error on the K, it should of been I.

Comment: First of all I would like to thank you for your prompt response. You have been very helpful and I am very thank ful for intelligent people like yourself. Well I tried the code but I get a syntax error.

Comment: It's best not to edit my response - you can ask questions in the comments.  What is the syntax error you get?  AS for which workbook is to be the source or destination, my code assumes that when you run the extract the active workbook is the one you want to review for completed items, and there is another workbook open named "Completed.xlsx" where the completed items will be moved to (on a sheet named "Complete")

Comment: Sorry about that, I will keep that in mind for the future, not to edit your original code. I get a syntax error towards the end and it points to Next rw

Comment: Should have been `Next x`

Comment: Oh, one more thing it didn't delete the rows that were copied to the completed workbook. do I have to input a range under your code that says "rw.EntireRow.Delete "  ?