# Importing data from another workbook on the next empty line

Tags: excel, vba, database, import, worksheet

Currently I'm trying to make a VBA for the following action:

- Worksheet A - standard worksheet where sales managers can enter the necessary information for a sales order.
- Worksheet B - The overview where all the lines of the order needs to be visible on a different way.

I'm looking for a code that when you activate the macro in worksheet B, you can insert the path of Worksheet A and he reads all the necessary items in worksheet B. But it has two important things what I need to take into account. 1) Always put the latest information on the next empty row in worksheet B. 2) In Worksheet A it has different values on different columns/rows, as example the price of the sales order is 650EUR and it visible on cell A3 from worksheet A. This value needs to be imported than in worksheet B under a specific place, as example: A3 from Worksheet A needs to be put on B4. And this counts also for the other variables from the sales order.

Who can help me out?

Comment: Have you checked out similar questions on here?

Comment: I have found some codes, but I couldn't find a code where I can find the code to put the values on specific places in the worksheet.

Comment: There are questions with code about finding the last non-blank cell to paste in the next one etc.

Comment: see this for one of many similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33226115/4961700